# Limiting the amount of times a User can make a comment

Tags: python, django

Say I have django models like so

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    commentDescription = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    commentOwner = models.ForeignKey(User1,null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, null=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    postDescription = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    postOwner = models.ForeignKey(User1,null=True)

class User1(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.user.username
```

Now when someone creates a `Post` I have to limit the amount of `Comment`'s made by a specific `User1` so that the `Post` can have a lot of `Comment`'s but only allow three `Comment`'s per `User1` on the `Post`

I am thinking of creating some kind of method that checks how many comments a user has already made on a specific post but I have no idea where to start with the complexity of the foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Whoops, missunderstood your question. Thought you would like to limit voting timebased, not with an absolut voting count :).

I would add a [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield) to the `Comment` model and then check in the `views.py` if he is allowed to create a new comment. (Or if you have a `CommentForm` you could check it there with a custom [is_valid](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_valid))

In pseudocode-like it would be something like this to check if a comment is allowed again.

```
if (comment_date < timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=min_comment_time)):
    // allow comment
```

Answer (score 0):

For a given user trying to comment on a given post, you can call the following method. `user` and `post` should be instances of the `User1` and `Post` model respectively.

```
def allow_comment(user, post):
    user_comments = post.comment_set.filter(
        commentOwner=user,
    )
    current_count = user_comments.count()
    if current_count < 3:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This method should be called from the view where the user is going to be commenting. If you want to instead return the number of comments of that `user` on that `post` and use it, simply return `current_count`.